# Is FFmpeg able to read multiple values in an ID3v2.4 tag?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, id3

Altough FFmpeg states that it has support for ID3v2.4 tags, there is one thing I can't get to work properly. The [ID3v2.4 specifications](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames) state the following:

> There may only be one text information frame of its kind in an tag.
>   All text information frames supports multiple strings, stored as a
>   null separated list, where null is represented by the termination code
>   for the character encoding.

However, when I use FFprobe, it only shows the first value. For example [mid3v2](http://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/man/mid3v2.html) shows the tags correctly. See below for both the outputs.

*mid3v2:*

```
mid3v2 --list 01_Infinite_\(Original_Mix\).mp3
IDv2 tag info for 01_Infinite_(Original_Mix).mp3
TALB=Infinite
TBPM=150
TCON=Hardstyle / Test / Example / Hard Dance
TDRC=2017
TIT2=Infinite (Original Mix)
TPE1=B-Front / Second Artist Example
TPE2=B-Front
TPUB=Roughstate
```

*FFmpeg:*

```
ffprobe -hide_banner 01_Infinite_\(Original_Mix\).mp3
Input #0, mp3, from '01_Infinite_(Original_Mix).mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : Infinite (Original Mix)
    artist          : B-Front
    album           : Infinite
    date            : 2017
    genre           : Hardstyle
    TBPM            : 150
    album_artist    : B-Front
    publisher       : Roughstate
```

The TCON (Genre) and TPE1 (Artist) fields have multiple values, seperated by a NULL-character. FFmpeg doesn't show more than one field.

Am I overlooking something, or is this just not implemented in FFmpeg/libavformat?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK these are ID3v2.3 tags, not ID3v1. ID3v1 is completely different.

Comment: Possibly, but the MP3 demuxer does not use the v2 parser to dump them.

Comment: Strike the above. ffmpeg only dumps id3v2. I'll look into this later.

Answer (score 0):

No. Although ttags in ID3 v2.4 support multiple strings, the ID3v2 parser terminates string extraction when it hits NULL, instead of consuming the full tag length.

Submit a bug report at https://trac.ffmpeg.org.

Comment: Allright, submitted a bug report. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6949

Comment: Attach a sample file there which has text tag with multiple strings.

Comment: Done, sample file attached.